# Dual IPv4 and IPv6 support in Flask applications

Tags: flask, ipv6

Would it be possible to run Flask to listen in both IPv4 and IPv6 (i.e. dual IP stack)? As far as I checked it is possible to run either in IPv4 using:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

or IPv6 using

```
app.run(host='::', port=port, debug=True)
```

but I haven't find a way of running in both at the same time (it is possible to have an instance of my Flask application listening to IPv4 and another instance listening to IPv6, but both cannot listen to the same port).

Thanks!

**Update (additional info):**

Followingt Sander Steffann comments (thanks!), I have started my app listening in IPv6:

```
* Running on http://[::]:1028/
* Restarting with reloader
```

Then test with IPv6 and IPv4 curls:

```
curl -g [::1]:1028/notify
curl 127.0.0.1:1028/notify
```

getting respectively:

```
::1 - - [10/Feb/2014 12:04:51] "GET /notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2014 12:05:03] "GET /notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

My interpretation of the second line is that "somebody" (the OS? the underlying networking libraries in which Flask relies upon?) is converting the IPv4 request to IPv6 request. However, I understand that is not the same that supporting IPv4 "natively" in a classical dual stack setup, i.e. I would have expected something linke this (that is what I get when I run my application (`Running on http://0.0.0.0:1028/`)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2014 12:05:03] "GET /notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: If they can't listen on the same port then very probably the IPv6 instance is also accepting IPv4 connections (i.e. V6ONLY is off). Can you test this?

Comment: Thanks @SanderSteffann! I have done that test and update the body of the question consequently.

Comment: I added an answer below. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What happens is that the operating system automatically attaches incoming IPv4 requests to the listening IPv6 socket. The IPv4 address is [mapped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) to an IPv6 address by prefixing it with `::ffff:`. Therefore an incoming IPv4 connection from `127.0.0.1` looks like it is coming from IPv6 address `::ffff:127.0.0.1`.

From the client's point of view it is talking to an IPv4 server. The client cannot tell the difference. From the server's point of view everybody is connecting using IPv6. The operating system performs the mapping between IPv4 packets and the IPv6 software.

The effect of this is that you can develop software without manually having to deal with dual stack programming. All software can be written for IPv6 and deal with all addresses as IPv6 addresses. This can simplify the code (no need to deal with having both a listening IPv4 and a listening IPv6 sockets etc.) while still providing a full dual-stack experience to the 'outside'.

So your service is fully dual-stack as seen from outside your system. In the application itself you will see the whole world represented with IPv6 addresses though, like you show in your log file. That usually doesn't cause any problems. It might affect the way you handle ACLs, logging and other things like that though.

Comment: Using the accepted solution, was still giving me issues when running curl -6 on the host name. It was not accepting IPv6 addresses. When I just used IPv6 it worked. `app.run(host='::', 4060)` Running my app on just `::` handled all the use cases (IPv4 and IPv6) for me, while prefixing IPv4 addresses. This might be in newer versions of flask.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, while Linux uses mapped IPv4 addresses to qualify "::", this does not work on several other IPv6 stacks, such as on Microsoft Windows. "::" will bind to the IPv6 address family, as for security reasons, Windows and other IPv6 stack implementors have decided to against mapping IPv4 addresses into the IPv6 address space, unless an application especially signals to do so. The rationale here, as far as I understand the discussion, is that otherwise unexpected IPv4 connectivity would happen that could undermine ACLs, or other application-layer security mechanisms.

Comment: FYI on Windows you can [opt-in to "dual-stack sockets"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/dual-stack-sockets#creating-a-dual-stack-socket) by setting the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option to `0` before binding to an address. On Linux the same socket option can be set to `1` to [opt _out_](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) of this behaviour.