# Python flask dual-stack on WINDOWS (ipv4 and ipv6)

Tags: python, windows, sockets, flask, ipv6

I'm using python Flask on Windows 10. It works fine for ipv4 or ipv6, depending on the ip I bind, but not both at the same time.

With this example:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World! <strong>I am learning Flask</strong>", 200

app.run(host='', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRkz9.png)

With this example:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World! <strong>I am learning Flask</strong>", 200

app.run(host='::', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nMxD.png)

When I run a minecraft server and bind it to "::", I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPMlW.png)

I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673068/dual-ipv4-and-ipv6-support-in-flask-applications) post that Flask does dual-stacking on Linux when binding to "::".
I would like to know if it's possible to make de Flask app listen to both ipv4 and ipv6 address at the same time.
Thanks.

Additional info:
Python socket module does not dual stack on windows (i think it does on Linux). I found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578504-server-supporting-ipv4-and-ipv6/) and managed to create a dual stack socket with this example:

```py
import socket
from recipe1 import has_dual_stack, create_server_sock, MultipleSocketsListener
tcp = MultipleSocketsListener([("0.0.0.0", 5000), ("::", 5000)])
while True:
    con, cliente = tcp.accept()
    print ('Concetado por', cliente)
    while True:
        msg = con.recv(1024)
        if not msg: break
        print (cliente, msg)
    print ('Finalizando conexao do cliente', cliente)
    con.close()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtxmJ.png)
It does work, but I don't know if this socket can be used with Flask.

Comment: don't put text as image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[PalletProjects.Flask]: *run*(*host=None, port=None, debug=None, load_dotenv=True, **options*)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.run):

> Do not use `run()` in a production setting. It is not intended to meet security and performance requirements for a production server. Instead, see [Deployment Options](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/#deployment) for WSGI server recommendations.

*NGINX* knows how to handle this exact scenario.

In development mode, I don't know why is so important to listen on all addresses, as things can be tested listening on one at a time.

I didn't see any easy way of making this work. As a note, on *Lnx* things seem to be easier as the *IPv4-mapped* *IPv6* addresses are controlled via the `net.ipv6.bindv6onl` setting.

There are however a number of ways to work things around, here's one that executes the current file (itself) in a new process for each listening *IP* address (and does it in a thread, since the (child) process blocks the execution).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from flask import Flask
import threading
import subprocess


app = Flask(__name__)


def run_flask(host):
    return subprocess.call([sys.executable, sys.argv[0], host])


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World! <strong>I am learning Flask</strong>", 200


def main(argv):
    port = 5000
    debug = True

    if argv:
        app.run(host=argv[0], port=port, debug=debug)
    else:
        hosts = [
            "127.0.0.1",
            "::1",
        ]

        threads = list()
        for host in hosts:
            threads.append(threading.Thread(target=run_flask, args=(host,)))

        for idx, thread in enumerate(threads):
            print("Starting on {0:s}:{1:d}".format(hosts[idx], port))
            thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output** (it's a bit mixed):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057881991]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Starting on 127.0.0.1:5000
> Starting on ::1:5000
>
> Done.
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>  * Serving Flask app "code00" (lazy loading)
>  * Serving Flask app "code00" (lazy loading)
>  * Environment: production
>  * Environment: production
>    WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
>    Use a production WSGI server instead.
>
>  * Debug mode: on
>    Use a production WSGI server instead.
>  * Debug mode: on
>  * Restarting with stat
>  * Restarting with stat
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>
>  * Debugger is active!
>  * Debugger is active!
>  * Debugger PIN: 566-002-078
>  * Debugger PIN: 566-002-078
>  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>  * Running on http://[::1]:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
> ```

As seen, the servers start listening on the given addresses (you can remove the *print* calls, in order to have less output). Also (on another *cmd*):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\WINDOWS\system32]> netstat -an | findstr 5000
>   TCP    127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
>   TCP    [::1]:5000             [::]:0                 LISTENING
> ```

You could also operate at *OS* level, by playing with the */etc/hosts* file, but I didn't test that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution using two threads worked for me. Thanks for pointing that run() should not be used in production setting. I will try to implement your solution using Gevent WSGI. My problem is solved, thank you!